# How would I create an android app with an array stored on a web server using android studio?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a 'shower thoughts' app. It has three categories stored in arrays. Underneath each are nested the actual list of user posts that the user can see (as arrays) . Of course, a user wont be able to see others posts. I have a rasbpi I am using as a webserver. The way I thought of doing this is a bit of javascript code on the web server that contain two functions: One that adds a users post to an array (with the input arguements being the post itself) and one that returns the array so that the app can update. However, I have no idea how to CALL this js file on the web server from the application. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to construct a web API for this. You can do this using [NodeJS on the server](https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/secure-rest-api-in-nodejs) and then [send requests to this API](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple) in Android

Comment: How would I run that on eht server? Node server just says it cant find a folder called server and the files in it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are trying to do is create a simple *Server-Client* Architecture.

There are multiple ways to do so. I am going to explain using [NodeJS](https://nodejs.dev) as the server and volley on the client (android) side.

Firstly you can use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley), to create an API call from android, that would interact with the NodeJS API, which in turn will create the array and store it in either SQL or any other form you want.

For reference you can check out this two projects. 
This is an [Android app](https://github.com/Pronoy999/ProjectSantaClaus/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/pm/wd/sl/college/projectsantaclaus/Helper/HTTPConnector.java) which is using Volley to communicate with the server. 
This is the [NodeJS Server](https://github.com/Pronoy999/Project_Santa-Claus-Server/blob/master/index.js) which is a simple REST API.

You can also use this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp) to learn basics about NodeJS if you don't know.

**This is the basic NodeJS code to create a server and then send a response to the client.**

```
var http = require('http');

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
  res.end(); //end the response
}).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

**This is the basic Android Volley code to make a request to the server.**

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        textView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,5));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        textView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

If you don't understand any of these code you can comment below.